# update pivot chart in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am in the process of recreating a VBA program in C#, and have run into an issue while updating pivot charts.
I have googled myself silly with this one and all i can find is (sketchy) information on setting up a new chart. The process itself seems pretty straightforward, i just cant seem to find the words to translate into in C#.
(i am a layman so excuse me if any of my terminology is "incorrect")

The code i am trying to port across (VBA -> C#) is;

```
Worksheets(MBTChartPage1).Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Daily1").Activate
ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Trial Date").ClearAllFilters
ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Trial Date").PivotFilters.Add2 _
Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:="01/01/2015", Value2:=Format(Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

i can activate the sheet that contains the chart, but thats where i stumble. I cant figure out how to select the chart, let alone edit it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if its just advice on how to activate (select) the chart by name.

Thank you in advance.

----UPDATE---

wow. this seems to be stumping a lot of people.

Currently working through this process, not even slightly sure if i'm on the right path, but hey, Challenges are exciting aren't they!?

```
MBTChartPage = UpdateBook.Worksheets[MBTChartPage1];
Excel.Chart PChart = MBTChartPage.ChartObjects("Daily1");
Excel.PivotFields PFields = PChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Trial Date");
PChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.ClearAllFilters();
```

just need to;

A) see if this works so far,

B) find out how to add the date filter back in.

---

Short answer, No. That doesn't work.
I have found how to select the table by name though;

```
            MBTChartPage = UpdateBook.Worksheets[MBTChartPage1];
            MBTChartPage.Activate();
            Excel.ChartObjects chartObject2 = MBTChartPage.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
            Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)chartObject2.Item("Daily1");
            Excel.Chart ChartSelect = myChart.Select();
```

Just working on clearing and resetting the filter now.
Half way there.

---

GET IN!!!

Solved it.

```
            MBTChartPage = UpdateBook.Worksheets[MBTChartPage1];
            MBTChartPage.Activate();
            Excel.ChartObjects chartObject2 = MBTChartPage.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
            Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)chartObject2.Item("Daily1");
            Excel.Chart ChartSelect = myChart.Select();
            myChart.Chart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Trial Date").ClearAllFilters();
            myChart.Chart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Trial Date").PivotFilters.Add2(XlPivotFilterType.xlDateBetween, Type.Missing, "01/01/2015", DateTime.Today);
```

Assuming (untested) that the "Select" statements can be removed from this. Only had them in there for a visual cue that the code was working.
However, this will select the chart by name, clear the filter , then reset the filter to between the first specified date and today.

I love coding! so frustrating, yet so damned rewarding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
            MBTChartPage = UpdateBook.Worksheets[MBTChartPage1];
            MBTChartPage.Activate();
            Excel.ChartObjects chartObject2 = MBTChartPage.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
            Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)chartObject2.Item("Daily1");
            Excel.Chart ChartSelect = myChart.Select();
            myChart.Chart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Trial Date").ClearAllFilters();
            myChart.Chart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Trial Date").PivotFilters.Add2(XlPivotFilterType.xlDateBetween, Type.Missing, "01/01/2015", DateTime.Today);
```

I'm assuming (untested) that the "Select" statements can be removed from this. Only had them in there for a visual cue that the code was working. However, this will select the chart by name, clear the filter , then reset the filter to between the first specified date and today.